# TPU gets stuck in Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, tpu

I am trying to run some code on TPU using GoogleColab.

I took inspiration on Tensorflow tutorial.

It initializes the TPU as it should, it seems to run perfectly until it reaches the first epoch of training and then it just stops.

Nothing happens anymore, it does not break, the RAM is not full, but it never go further.

I already restarted multiple times the environment but nothing changed.

```py
autoencoder.fit(
    dataset.batch(1024),
    epochs=100,
    steps_per_epoch=200,
    verbose=1,
    callbacks=[ModelCheckpoint('weights.{epoch:02d}-{loss:.2f}.hdf5', monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')]
)
```

And the definition of the model:

```py
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
TPU_WORKER = 'grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR']
print(f"TPU: {TPU_WORKER}")
cluster = tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(TPU_WORKER)
tf.contrib.distribute.initialize_tpu_system(cluster)
strategy = tf.contrib.distribute.TPUStrategy(cluster)
with strategy.scope():
    bvae = ResNetAutoEncoder()
    autoencoder = bvae.ae
    autoencoder.compile(
        optimizer=optimizers.Adam(),
        loss='mean_absolute_error'
    )
```

I see the following:

```
Epoch 1/100
W0728 18:42:12.563039 139622569146240 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_distributed.py:411: Variable.load (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Prefer Variable.assign which has equivalent behavior in 2.X.
```

It seems to be working but even after more than an hour, nothing more happened.

The TPU is at 0% use according to the Google Cloud Platform (when I tried on my own TPU).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a late reply, I assumed you tried with Tensorflow 2.0, please try out Tensorflow 2.1 or 2.2. Only from Tensorflow 2.1 Keras .compile, .fit, .evaluate, and .predict APIs are available for TPUs. Here is the Tensorflow 2.1 [release notes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.1.0).

For Tensorflow 2.1+ the code to initialize a TPUStrategy will be:

```
TPU_WORKER = 'grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'] # for colab use TPU_NAME if in GCP.

resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(TPU_WORKER)
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(resolver)
```

Read [TPUStrategy guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training#tpustrategy) for more detail.